# DNS Resolves Externally But Not Internally

Tags: networking, router, dns

We have a Verizon Router and we have configured some port forwarding rules.

For example: port 8443 will go to one of our internal addresses 192.168.1.55.
We also have DNS entries for mysite.com to point to the Router Address.

When we are external and visit mysite.com:8443 - everything works as expected.
However if we are internal and visit mysite.com:8443 - it spins forever.

I am assuming we need an internal DNS server to resolve? Assuming this is the case and we set up an internal DNS (any info appreciated) - when a request originates inside the network - what is the resolution?

CHECK INTERNAL DNS (would map hostnames to local addresses) AND THEN CHECK EXTERNAL DNS (would map hostnames to router address)?

If anyone could provide any info or confirm what I am saying that would be great.

Additional Info:
Router Model: MI424WR-GEN3I
Found 'DNS Server' functionality that allows me to enter hostname + ip address combinations but it does not seem this is being used for resolution when i ping from a machine inside the network.

The router connects to a Watchguard XTM515 Firewall which has a DNS Server of 8.8.8.8 setup in its DNS Servers list.

Comment: Look for NAT loopback functionality within the router if applicable and test with it. Otherwise, yes, point the record DNS to the internal IP address of your server.

Comment: Thank you - I will do that. I did find a 'DNS Server' entry. in which I seem to be able to add host name / ip address entries within the router but when pinging they do not seem to resolve. The router model is MI424WR-GEN3I

Comment: No NAT Loopback functionality as far as I can see. I think the resolution has to do with the computer not using the router's dns tables. If i do an ipconfig /all should i see 192.168.1.1 as one of the DNS entries?

Comment: If you have a local DNS server, then point the DNS record to the internal IP address of your server. This way internally mysite.com will resolve to the internal IP rather than the public and have the NAT loopback issue where it gets confused going out the WAN and coming back in or whatever. You could modify each hosts file if you do not have a local DNS services, records, etc. https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/.

Comment: Can you do NAT loopback with Watchguard? You should be able to and point it accordingly from there. http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/11/en-US/Content/en-US/nat/nat_loopback_static_c.html

Comment: The hostsfile does work but it is tedious to manage hostfiles across X machines, considering we add new sites, teardown new sites etc. I will take a look @ NAT loopback with watchguard. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Nat loopback with watchguard seems very promising. We are running an older firmware version that made the docs hard to follow. We contacted Watchguard and they provided us directions on upgrading the firmware. We will be exploring NAT loopback in the Watchguard. Wish i could upvote you but I am new to superuser. Thanks Facebook!

Comment: Scott - No worries man, you can up vote later when you get more rep, etc. Tag me back on your findings and if you want and you confirm the NAT loopback with WG resolves, I'll be happy to add that as an answer for you to accept. Just keep me updated as you make progress on this with support, etc.Thanks for the update!!

Comment: Sounds good - Thanks for your assistance so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router seems to be lacking [NAT Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (also known as *NAT Loopback* or *NAT Reflection*). Similar features are also sometimes called *Reverse NAT*.

Note that this feature is sometimes simply disabled in a device. The quickest and easiest solution is to enable it (if possible), so you may wish to check your router settings before taking any additional steps.

> I am assuming we need an internal DNS server to resolve?

Setting up an internal DNS server could potentially resolve this issue, yes.

> Assuming this is the case and we set up [an internal DNS server] - when a request originates inside the network - what is the resolution?

Essentially, the computer asking for *mysite.com* needs to contact your internal DNS server before routing it to any additional sources (likely via forwarding). Your internal DNS server would simply have a local entry for *mysite.com* pointing to your local web server(s) (via internal IPs).

If you need DNS server software, [ISC BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloads/) is a good choice. It is robust and comes available for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Yes, I do not see any NAT hairpinning or NAT loopback in the router specs. There is a DNS table in the router which has: Hostname, IP and I tried entering my hostname / internal ip there. e.g.  dev.mysite.com 192.168.1.55 but no luck.  Running ipconfig /all I only see 8.8.8.8 listed under DNS servers. I tried to put 192.168.1.1 in the firewall, but it doesnt seem that worked. It seems my computer does not want to use the DNS in the router?

Comment: I found a bit of conflicting information regarding support for this feature in the router you have (apparently there are multiple revisions using the same basic name). That said, I found one credible site which suggests "bypassing" your router with a second (one that supports NAT loopback). It seems they were suggesting to possibly use the your device in some variation of bridge mode (where it only handles data, not routing). They indicated NAT loopback for your base model of Actiontec router doesn't always work well/consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the info Anaksunaman - Thats unfortunate to hear. Perhaps I can setup the loopback in the watchguard firewall as someone else suggested. Finding it hard to follow as the documentation and my UI seem to be slightly different possibly due to versions.

Comment: Confirmed by Watchguard - we were using an old version of the UI that did not have the options shown in their documentation. We will be thinking about upgrading at some point

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the update (and the checkmark =P).